# mod_rewrite - change URL case

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is there any straightforward way to change the case of any URL using mod_rewrite?

I thought this was pretty trivial... apparently not.

Examples:

http://example.com/id
to
http://example.com/ID

http://example.com/id/123
to
http://example.com/ID/123

and so forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mod_rewrite has some [internal functions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) you can use for a mapping. One of them is `toupper` that converts letters to uppercase:

```
RewriteMap uppercase int:toupper

RewriteRule [a-z] %{uppercase:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking to change case of only the ID. This one did the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^id(.*)$ /ID$1  [QSA,R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteMap uppercase int:toupper
RewriteRule ^/(^/)*$ /${uppercase:$1}  [L]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/(.*)$ /${uppercase:$1}/$2 [L]
```

(syntax unchecked)