# Case in-sensitive Jboss 7 web application context root

Tags: jboss7.x

Is there a way to make web application context case in-sensitive?

Basically i'm doing the following in jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>cap</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

I'm able to access the app via localhost:8080/cap, but trying to make it accessible via localhost:8080/Cap or localhost:8080/CAP. Any ideas please?

Comment: If you want tou use Apache in front of your server you can also check these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353807/mod-rewrite-change-url-case and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998156/case-insensitive-urls-with-mod-rewrite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put apache+mod_proxy in front of jboss and use url-rewriting or redirection (easier option).
Example of rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/Cap$ /cap/ [R]
RewriteRule ^/CAP$ /cap/ [R]
```

You would put the above to httpd.conf or a similar location.