# How to set the context root not to be case sensitive in JBoss 4?

Tags: java, jboss-4.2.x

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/offline</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

I'd like that both url will work

1. url/offline
2. url/Offline

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808655/jboss-possible-to-mount-a-war-on-two-different-context-paths

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

[Case in-sensitive Jboss 7 web application context root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470850/case-in-sensitive-jboss-7-web-application-context-root)

Its for Jboss 7, but I believe it can be applied the same way.

Combined with:

[mod_rewrite - change URL case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353807/mod-rewrite-change-url-case)