# mix-cased Apache rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have some resources at these paths:

```
/application/myFoo
/application/myBar
```

always 'my' followed by a capitalized name

I'd like to redirect

```
/myfoo, /myFOO, /myFoo, (even /foo, /Foo if possible)
```

to the first one, and likewise for the second url

```
RewriteRule ^/my(.*) /application/my$1 [L,NC]
```

is my solution for the moment, it works for /myFoo, /mYFoo, but nor for /myfoo, /foo

reference: [mod_rewrite - change URL case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353807/mod-rewrite-change-url-case) (it's a little different since I don't want to have all %{REQUEST_URI} uppercased

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?(?:my)?([a-z])(.*) /application/my${uppercase:$1}${lowercase:$2} [L,NC]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's one possible solution

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteMap uppercase int:toupper
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(lib|system|application)/
RewriteRule ^/?(?:my)?([a-z])(.*) /application/my${uppercase:$1}${lowercase:$2} [L,NC]
```