# How to convert uppercase url to lowercase

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

In my website,
For example:

```
**http://example.com/products/New-York/Coffee-Table/1**
```

to

```
**http://example.com/products/new-york/coffee-table/1**
```

Comment: I don't know any php, but don't you just want [`strtolower`](http://php.net/strtolower)?

Comment: google and as @WaiHaLee pointed that  is the answer

Comment: why do you tag it as `mod-rewrite`? if that's what you asking, you can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353807/mod-rewrite-change-url-case

Comment: Are you asking how to do it in php or are you asking for a rewrite-rule for a htaccess file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP has a few built-in functions for converting string cases.

- [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

> `string strtolower ( string $string )`
>
> Returns string with all alphabetic characters converted to lowercase.
> Note that 'alphabetic' is determined by the current locale. This means that e.g. in the default "C" locale, characters such as umlaut-A (Ä) will not be converted.

- [`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)

> `string strtoupper ( string $string )`
>
> Returns string with all alphabetic characters converted to uppercase.
> Note that 'alphabetic' is determined by the current locale. For instance, in the default "C" locale characters such as umlaut-a (ä) will not be converted.

- [`mb_strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)

> `string mb_strtolower ( string $str [, string $encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )`
>
> Returns str with all alphabetic characters converted to lowercase.

- [`mb_strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php)

> `string mb_strtoupper ( string $str [, string $encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )`
>
> Returns str with all alphabetic characters converted to uppercase.

- [`mb_convert_case()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php)

> `string mb_convert_case ( string $str , int $mode [, string $encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )`
>
> Performs case folding on a string, converted in the way specified by mode.

--

Full documentation: http://php.net/docs.php

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in to `.htaccess` to force url to lowercase. Try this to your `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mb_strtolower($url)`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php). Use [`strtolower($url)`](https://php.net/strtolower) if you are not concerned about non-ASCII characters in the URL. `strtolower()` mishandles multibyte characters.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the inbuild PHP function **strtolower()** to convert your string to Lowercase.

```
$myUrl = "http://example.com/products/New-York/Coffee-Table/1";

$myModifiedUrl = strtolower($myUrl);

//$myModifiedUrl contents the string with lower case.
```

Hopefully you are looking for this.